# Display product under its category

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working in wordpress.I have display different subcategory.Now click on each category it will display its product under it.

My code is like this:

```
<?php
    $query3 = "select t.* from wp_terms as t 
               join wp_term_taxonomy as tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id
               where tt.parent = ".$res2->term_id;
    $result3 = $wpdb->get_results($query3);

    foreach($result3 as $res3)
    {
?>
        <li>
            <a href="##" class="sub_cat_name" data-id = "<?php echo $res3->term_id; ?>"><strong><?php echo $res3->name; ?></strong></a>
                <ul class="tmp">
                     <li class="tmp_li">
                     </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
<?php
     }
?>
```

And my jquery code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub_cat_name").click(function(){
        var cat_id = $(this).data("id");
        //alert(cat_id);
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url()."/category-products/?cat_id=" ?>" + cat_id,
        }).done(function(data){
            $(".tmp_li").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my ajax page is :

```
<?php
/** 
    Template Name: Get Category Products
*/
$cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
//echo $cat_id;

$query = "select p.* from wp_terms as t 
        join wp_term_taxonomy as tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id
        join wp_term_relationships as tr on tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        join wp_posts as p on p.ID = tr.object_id
        where t.term_id = ".$cat_id;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
//print_r($result);
foreach($result as $res)    
{
?>
    <div class="pro_name">
        <?php echo $res->post_title; ?>
    </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

I got my product under subcategory.But problem is that when I click on link then its product display in all subcategory.Instead of it I want to display products under only its own category not in all.

For instance

There are two subcategory:

1) Apple

2) Mango

When I click on Apple so its product display under apple not in mango.
Here I got apple product under apple as well as under mango. So what code should i have to write to solve this issue?

Comment: try to use GROUP BY `subcategory` , `product`

Comment: @JaiminMosLake it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed in my code and I it is working. My new code is like this.

```
<?php

                                            $query3 = "select t.* from wp_terms as t 
                                                        join wp_term_taxonomy as tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id
                                                        where tt.parent = ".$res2->term_id;
                                            $result3 = $wpdb->get_results($query3);


                                            foreach($result3 as $res3)
                                            {
                                        ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="##" class="sub_cat_name_<?php echo $res3->term_id; ?>" data-id = "<?php echo $res3->term_id; ?>"><strong><?php echo $res3->name; ?></strong></a>
                                                    <ul class="tmp_<?php echo $res3->term_id; ?>">
                                                        <li class="tmp_li_<?php echo $res3->term_id; ?>">
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>


                                        <script>
                                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                                $(".sub_cat_name_<?php echo $res3->term_id; ?>").click(function(){

                                                    //var subCategoru = $(this);
                                                    //alert(subCategoru);
                                                    //var tmp_li = subCategoru.siblings('tmp').find('tmp_li');
                                                    //alert(tmp_li);

                                                    var cat_id = $(this).data("id");
                                                    //alert(cat_id);
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url : "<?php echo site_url()."/category-products/?cat_id=" ?>" + cat_id,
                                                    }).done(function(data){
                                                        //tmp_li.html(data);
                                                        $(".tmp_li_<?php echo $res3->term_id; ?>").html(data);
                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                });
                                        </script>

                                        <?php
                                            }
                                        ?></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .... You have to find relational element for appending data.. otherwise it will append to every element which has that class...  If not work minor changes will require..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub_cat_name").click(function(){

    var subCategoru = $(this);
    vat tmp_li = subCategoru.siblings('tmp').find('tmp_li');


    var cat_id = $(this).data("id");
    //alert(cat_id);
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url()."/category-products/?cat_id=" ?>" + cat_id,
    }).done(function(data){
              tmp_li.html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: data does not append with tmp_li